# How are Flash files without class definitions compiled?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Let's use the code from the first section of [this](http://permadi.com/blog/2010/06/flash-as3-using-filereference-to-load-files-example-for-flash-cs4-and-above/) website. I don't see a class declaration, and my program cannot be built in FlashDevelop. I receive the following error message:

```
Error: A file found in a source-path must have an externally visible definition. If a definition in the file is meant to be externally visible, please put the definition in a package.
Build halted with errors (fcsh).
```

What should I do in order to be able to build & run it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using flash develop and pure AS3 (no flex) then everything has to be in a class and package.

Simply wrap that code in a custom class to use it in flashDevelop.  If you create a new project in flash develop most templates create a Main.as file - which is the root class that runs when you're project loads, just dump the code inside the Main class defined in that .AS file (except for the imports, they'll need to be inbetween the package and class declarations).

```
package {

    //imports here

    public class Main extends MovieClip {
       //put any vars that aren't in functions here  (eg. var mFileReference:FileReference)
       public function Main():void {
           //put anything not contained in a function here
       }

       //put the functions here

    }

}
```

Comment: You're going to run into the same problem as your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12060031/how-could-i-compile-the-code-for-this-flash-tutorial/12060072#12060072 though because the code is expecting display objects to be already initialized from the flash IDE

Comment: Yeah, I noticed. I guess I have to start using Flash IDE :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answers, and for taking the time with a flash beginner such as myself!

Comment: You could use the flex components, or just create your own button/progress bar via code

Comment: Could you provide an example of using the components? For example, the components in the `fl` package don't seem to exist on my system. Or perhaps I should add something to the classpath?

Comment: fl package is for the flash IDE.   mx package is the flex exquivelant.  What you would need to do is create a new Flex 4 Project in flash develop, then use the Main.mxml file to markup your UI elements.  http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=02_Getting_Started__23.html

Comment: That shows some sample markup on how to make/declare buttons and labels.

Comment: Then, in the <fx:Script> section, you could copy paste the exact code from those samples as long as you named your display assets what the code is expecting.

Comment: You have been extremely helpful! Thank you very much! Thanks to your answers, I'm actually asking more `relevant` questions now: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12062651/externalinterface-give-me-an-option-of-stopping-the-script-when-using-multiple-p